Ошибка при попытке запустить JavaScript-код в Visual Studio Code с помощью дополнения Code Runner
При попытке запустить Javascript-код в Visual Studio Code с помощью дополнения CodeRunner я получаю следующую ошибку в выходных данных:
"[Running] node "c:\Users\Daniil\Desktop\3 + 2.js"
"node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.02 seconds".

Я установил node.js ранее, поэтому при проверке установки через Windows Powershell с помощью команды "node --version" я получаю результат "v20.12.2".
